# Windows Audio Routing

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have struggled with the audio output routing in windows for years. I start by right clicking on the speaker icon in the task bar and then just muddle through until I eventually get the sound coming out where I want.  I have to select Playback Devices then try to make the output I want the default device and if I'm successful, it normally works.

This is incredibly counter-intuitive... is there a way I can just see the available devices and simply select the one I want?  Is there a better way to go in and select this than using the task bar icon?

I'm currently using Windows 7 but this is an age old problem for men.

Comment: Yeah, Windows has always had horrible sound implementation - try one of these, see if it helps - https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-change-or-switch-the-default-audio-sound-output-in-windows-vista-and-xp/

Comment: @Tetsujin excellent, plus 1. I will check those out.  Glad to hear I'm not the only one that finds this rediculous.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the best solution so far, been opting in for one year...
https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router

However in order to run it in non-admin mode one has to create a shortcut link with the following parameters:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & start "" /b "C:\NoInstall\Audio Router.exe" & exit
```

Valid as of 2018/1/21,
Cheers.